# A good description of the random forests method

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

Can anyone suggest a good book or article describing the random forests method of classification? I'm not satisfied with the way the subject is treated in "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R " by Tibshirani & Co 
and would like to have a more or less rigorous but comprehensible description.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want something "more" rigorous or "less" rigorous?

Comment: More mathematically rigorous and detailed (although skipping of some details is allowed).

Answer (score 5):

Did you check out "The Elements of Statistical Learning" http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/ (free online pdf). It is the more advanced version of "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R "

If that is not appropriate I would probably just start reading the original journal articles that are listed as references in the relevant chapters of these books.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that I need to read a substantial part of 400 pages in order to understand the chapter about random forests in "The Elements of Statistical Learning". I was looking for something accessible for a mathematician who is familiar with LDA but isn't a specialist in machine learning.

Comment: @levgen this is not true. The chapter about RF is the Hastie is pretty much self-contained. The only prerequisite is that you go through the chapters about decision trees/CART, and Bagging. And in any other text you would need to understand these concepts before tackling RF.

Answer (score 5):

When getting up to speed on a topic, I find it helpful to start at the beginning and work forward chronologically. Breiman's [original paper](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/randomforest2001.pdf) on random forests is where I would recommend starting.

Leo Breiman. "Random Forests." *Machine Learning* (2001). 45, 5-32.

Comment: I agree, also try just programming up the algorithm on your own (its not that complicated). Going through an exercise like that can be illuminating

Answer (score 2):

There is a PhD thesis from one of the Kaggle guys about Understanding Random Forests. And that's actually the title of his thesis. This is the link and i think its a pretty new PhD:

http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~glouppe/pdf/phd-thesis.pdf

Hope this helps, it's more specific and starts from basics as well.

Comment: The link unfortunately does not work for me, but I think this is the document you were talking about: arXiv:1407.7502